# How to replace dot in linux

Tags: awk, gsub

I Have a file with a column as shown below:

```
1000g2012apr_all
  0.07
  0.17
  0.16
  0.23
  0.04
   .
  0.23
  0.15
  0.24
```

Using the solution,

```
  awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="\t"} {gsub(/\./,"",$1)}1'
```

replaces all the dots in the first column. But i would like to replace only those without any value. The output should look like below where . is replaced only in 6th row where there is no value. Could someone help to do this?

```
   1000g2012apr_all
  0.07
  0.17
  0.16
  0.23
  0.04

  0.23
  0.15
  0.24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove lone periods from tab-separated files.  In that case, your code needs only the most minor adjustment:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="\t"} {gsub(/^\.$/,"",$1)}1'  file
1000g2012apr_all
0.07
0.17
0.16
0.23
0.04

0.23
0.15
0.24
```

In the above, the regex `/\./` was replaced with `/^\.$/` to assure that nothing precedes or follows the period.

For this case, the use of regex can be eliminated.  If just test to see if `$1` is a period and, if so, remove it:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="\t"} $1 == "." {$1=""}1'  file
1000g2012apr_all
0.07
0.17
0.16
0.23
0.04

0.23
0.15
0.24
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for gensub() if you want to retain leading and/or trailing white space:

```
awk '{$0=gensub(/^([[:space:]]*)\.([[:space:]]*)$/,"\\1\\2","")}1'
```

if you don't care about retaining white space you can just do this with any awk:

```
awk '{sub(/^[[:space:]]*\.[[:space:]]*$/,"")}1'
```

Comment: i would like to work it on only a specific column, as shown in the initial solution ($1).

Comment: Update your question to show some more truly representative sample input and expected output (e.g. with multiple columns) if you can't adapt the posted solution to work for you. It's best if you provide the test cases than asking everyone else to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using awk I used `sed`.  This may not fit your use-case but just in case it does:

I put your example file above in a file on my linux box.  I then:

`sed -i 's/\s\+\.\s*$//g' filename` to do an in-text replacement.  Please note, **your file will be changed by this command so back it up first!!!**