# Remove dots but not decimals in tab delimited file

Tags: awk

I have these data:

```
    #chr    pos     ref     alt     af_alt  filter  an
22      10510033        T       C       .       AC0;AS_VQSR     0
22      10510061        A       T       0       AC0     2
(non-dot lines snipped)
22      10510286        G       A       0       AC0;AS_VQSR     1598
22      10510286        G       T       0.00125156      AS_VQSR 1598
```

I wantto remove lone dots in every column but, eg columns 1 for `af_alt` but leave decimals (eg last row)

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27205566/how-to-replace-dot-in-linux) solution, but does not seem to change the file in anyway:

`awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="    "} {gsub(/^\.$/,"",$1)}1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk you can do:

```
awk  -v OFS="\t" '/\./{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i==".") $i=""} 1' file
```

This works on any field (where a regex relying on a leading or trailing space does not) and allows awk to handle the surrounding field separators. That allows simple string equality to be used to test for `"."`.

With your example (with the runs of spaces replaced with tabs) prints:

```
#chr    pos ref alt af_alt  filter  an
22  10510033    T   C       AC0;AS_VQSR 0
22  10510061    A   T   0   AC0 2
22  10510077    C   A   0   AC0 18
22  10510103    A   T   0   AC0;AS_VQSR 64
22  10510105    T   A   0   AC0;AS_VQSR 70
22  10510113    C   T   0   AC0;AS_VQSR 94
22  10510119    A   G   0   AC0;AS_VQSR 120
22  10510130    A   G   0   AC0;AS_VQSR 164
22  10510138    CATA    C   0   AC0;AS_VQSR 218
22  10510143    T   A   0   AC0;AS_VQSR 264
22  10510161    T   A   0   AC0;AS_VQSR 430
22  10510164    A   T   0   AC0;AS_VQSR 468
22  10510169    G   A   0   AS_VQSR 502
22  10510171    C   T   0   AC0;AS_VQSR 530
22  10510183    A   G   0   AS_VQSR 718
22  10510193    G   C   0   AC0;AS_VQSR 804
22  10510200    C   T   0   AC0;AS_VQSR 936
22  10510212    A   T   0   AS_VQSR 1070
22  10510228    G   T   0   AC0;AS_VQSR 1318
22  10510232    A   G   0   AS_VQSR 1364
22  10510233    G   A   0   AC0 1370
22  10510235    C   A   0   AC0;AS_VQSR 1376
22  10510236    G   A   0   AC0 1394
22  10510250    C   T   0   AC0;AS_VQSR 1434
22  10510258    C   T   0   AS_VQSR 1442
22  10510263    A   T   0   AC0;AS_VQSR 1486
22  10510276    G   A   0   AC0;AS_VQSR 1550
22  10510277    A   G   0   AC0;AS_VQSR 1570
22  10510286    G   A   0   AC0;AS_VQSR 1598
22  10510286    G   T   0.00125156  AS_VQSR 1598
```

Comment: Make sure to set `OFS = "\t"`

Answer (score 1):

You might harness GNU `sed` for this task following way, let `file.txt` be tab-sheared with following content

```
1.1 2.2 3.3
1.1 2.2 .
1.1 .   3.3
1.1 .   .
.   2.2 3.3
.   2.2 .
.   .   3.3
.   .   .
```

then

```
sed -e 's/^\.\t/\t/' -e 's/\t\.$/\t/' -e 's/\t\.\t/\t\t/g' file.txt
```

gives output

```
1.1 2.2 3.3
1.1 2.2 
1.1     3.3
1.1     
    2.2 3.3
    2.2 
        3.3
```

Explanation: there are 3 cases: `.` might be at beginning of line, `.` might be at end of line, `.` might be in middle of line. 1st and 2nd is done using `^` (start of line) and `$` (end of line) and it is sufficient to do each once, 3rd might require global (`g`) replacement, each is replace with number of TAB characters from match (1, 1 and 2 respectively). Observe that `.` needs to be escaped to mean literal dot, not any character.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.7)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to replace any dot between spaces by a space:

```
sed 's/ \. /   /'
```

For the last column, you might need a `$` instead of the final space.

Comment: That does not seem to work either, I have double checked that it is a tab delimited file: cat myfile | tr " " "*" | tr "\t" "&"

Comment: wait I think this maybe: sed 's/\t\.\t/\t\t/'

Comment: This won't work on the first or last column. Should be `sed -E 's/(^|\t)\.(\t|$)/\1\2/g' file`

Answer (score 0):

For a regex solution, I'd use perl

```bash
perl -pe 's/(^|\t)\.(\t|$)/$1$2/g'
```

Demo:

Some tab-separated text:

```bash
$ printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' 1 2 3 4 . 5 . 7.5 .
1       2       3
4       .       5
.       7.5     .
```

with the perl filter

```bash
$ printf '%s\t%s\t%s\n' 1 2 3 4 . 5 . 7.5 . | perl -pe 's/(^|\t)\.(\t|$)/$1$2/g'
1       2       3
4               5
        7.5
```

Comment: Same works with sed: `sed -E 's/(^|\t)\.(\t|$)/\1\2/g' file `

Comment: You can use look arounds so you don't need captures: `perl -pe 's/(?:^|(?<=\t))\.(?=\t|$)//g'`, or even `s/(?<=\t|^)\.(?=\t|$)//g` in recent Perl versions.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't wanna deal with loops but also don't mind an extra downstream pipe:

> ```
> {m,g,n}awk 'gsub("\23\\456", "\23_", $!(NF = NF))^_' OFS='\23' |
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> column -s$'\23' -t
> ```

```
#chr      pos       ref       alt  af_alt      filter       an
22        10510033  T         C    _           AC0;AS_VQSR  0
22        10510061  A         T    0           AC0          2
(non-dot  lines     snipped)
22        10510286  G         A    0           AC0;AS_VQSR  1598
22        10510286  G         T    0.00125156  AS_VQSR      1598
```